# LINQ with GROUP BY and filter by COUNT on specific column/field

Tags: linq

How to translate below SQL to LINQ (query syntax)

```
select t1.id, t1.col2
from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.t1_id
group by t1.id, t1.col2
having count(t2.id) = 0
```

Table2 schema

- id - PK
- t1_id - FK to Table1

This what I have so far. I cannot figure the "having count(t2.id) = 0" part

```
from t1 in context.Table1
join t2 in context.Table2 on t1.id equals t2.t1_id into tgroup
from t2t in tgroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
group t2t by new { t1.col1, t1.col2 } into g
where g.Count ==> THE PROBLEM
select new { g.Key.id, g.Key.col2 }
```

Comment: Only tag the technologies you want a solution in...

Comment: Which EF Core version?

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Comment: In `Table1`, how it possible to group by `t1.id` - are there multiple t1 rows with the same `id`?

Comment: How about `where g.All(t2 => t2 == null)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you do not need `HAVING` here. Just check that right record do not exists:

```cs
var query = 
    from t1 in context.Table1
    join t2 in context.Table2 on t1.id equals t2.t1_id into tgroup
    from t2 in tgroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where t2 == null
    group t1 by new { t1.id, t1.col2 } into g
    select new { g.Key.id, g.Key.col2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this:

```
from t1 in context.Table1 join t2 in 
context.Table2 on t1.id equals t2.t1_id 
into tgroup 
from t2t in 
tgroup.DefaultIfEmpty() 
group t2t by new { 
t1.col1, t1.col2 } into g     
select new { g.Key.id, g.Key.col2, sum = g.Sum(t2.col2) }
```

Comment: t2.col2 and t1.id are non-numeric, I think Sum will not work